# Enum Values to Array

Tags: arrays, typescript, enums

i want to get only the values of an enum as an array. So if you have:

```
    enum A {
        dog = 1,
        cat = 2,
        ant = 3
    }
```

What i want: `["dog", "cat", "ant"]` by:

```
    Object.values(A)
```

but it gets you: `["dog", "cat", "ant", 0, 1, 2]`

Also the values returned `(0, 1, 2)` would not match the given ones `(1, 2, 3)` anyway.
How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer you can't since typescript would compile your enum into the following

```js
var A;
(function (A) {
    A[A["dog"] = 1] = "dog";
    A[A["cat"] = 2] = "cat";
    A[A["ant"] = 3] = "ant";
})(A || (A = {}));
```

[link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAglDeAoKKoBMD2BzKBeKAjADTKoDGAhgC55QBMJqUFIN+AzIgL5A)

however, since enums can't have numeric keys you can do the following to get the keys

```js
Object.keys(A).filter(isNaN)
```

this works because an Enum can't contain a numeric value as an entry